# Using applescript to open a page in notion (on Mac)

Tags: safari, applescript

I am trying to set up a script to open a specific page in the notion app. So far I've tried the following:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell window 1
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"notion://www.notion.so/Focus-Mode-5eca2183453748d3b5acaa8e7292ef83"})
    end tell
end tell
```

but Safari requires that you give permission to open the app. Is there anyway to get around this? If not, is there anyway to open the page in Notion without having to go through Safari?

Comment: In other browsers there's the option to always allow those links to be opened. Even if you don't use one, you could still give the task to a browser such as Google Chrome.

Comment: Chrome seems to no longer offer this as an option. Firefox does, but when the url is entered via applescripts it still asks for permisson.

Answer (score 3):

It can be even simpler:
I was playing with your solution and found out that even though you can't finde those commands in the dictionary, they still exist:

```
tell application "Notion"
    open location "notion:page:Focus-Mode-5eca2183453748d3b5acaa8e7292ef83"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution - this was painfully obvious...

```
tell application "Notion"
   open location "notion://www.notion.so/Focus-Mode-5eca2183453748d3b5acaa8e7292ef83"
end tell
```